# ASP.Net MVC 3 Custom HTML Helper - How to pass List<T> to helper using Object Literal Notation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to build a helper to create a simple single level menu. Upon calling the menu helper I would like to use object literal notation so that I can define the menu items in the view.

```
public class ActionsMenuHelper
{

    public static string ActionsMenu(IList<ActionsMenuItem> menuItems)
    {
        string result = "";

        return result;
    }


}
```

I am just not sure on the syntax to call the menu.
I have tried something like.

```
@ActionsMenuHelper.ActionsMenu(List<ActionsMenuItem>{ new {Name = "Foo"},
                                                   new {Name = "Bar"}
                                                 });
```

I'm obviously lost on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're quite close. Try this:

```
@ActionsMenuHelper.ActionsMenu(new List<ActionsMenuItem> { new ActionsMenuItem { Name = "Foo" }, new ActionsMenuItem { Name = "Bar" }});
```

Can get a little messy if you have more than a couple items, though.  I'd define the list ahead of time for readability:

```
@{ 
    var menuItems = new List<ActionsMenuItem> {
        new ActionsMenuItem { Name = "Foo" },
        new ActionsMenuItem { Name = "Bar" },
        new ActionsMenuItem { Name = "Etc" }
    };
}

@ActionsMenuHelper.ActionsMenu(menuItems);
```

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).